# Is $H^\infty(\mathbb{C_+}) \subset H^2(\mathbb{C_+})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

I know that $H^\infty(\mathcal{D}(0,1)) \subset H^2(\mathcal{D}(0,1))$, and that there is a mapping $$f: \mathcal{D}(0,1)\to  \mathbb{C}_+ : z\mapsto s=\frac{1-z}{1+z}.$$

However in  $\mathbb{C_+}$ I have an "infinite domain of integration" somehow, so I don;t know if the result can be extended.

Answer (score 1):

The constant function $1$ belongs to $H^{\infty}(\mathbb C_{+})$ but not to $H^{2}(\mathbb C_{+})$.